# Symfony 5 - Use Assert Expression in a form

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, expression, assert

I would like use Expression constraint from the form.

Now, I've my Expression constraint in my entity, like this :

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Choice(choices=TypeConge::TYPE_SOLDE, message="Veuillez choisir une valeur valide.")
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "not (this.getId() != null and this.getTypeSolde() != this.getConfirmTypeSolde())",
     *     message="Vous ne pouvez pas modifier le type de solde d'un type de congé que vous avez déjà créé ! ({{ value }})"
     * )
     */
    private ?string $typeSolde = null;
```

I want now move it in the formType :

In my FormType, I've :

```php
->add('typeSolde', ChoiceType::class, [
                //...
                'constraints' => [
                    new Expression([
                        'expression' => 'not (this.getId() != null and this.getTypeSolde() != this.getConfirmTypeSolde())',
                        'message' => "Vous ne pouvez pas modifier le type de solde d'un type de congé que vous avez déjà créé ! ({{ value }})"
                    ])
                ]
            ])
```

But it returns me the following error :

```
Unable to call method "getId" of object "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".
```

In the doc, it doesn't say how can we do

Comment: Here's an example from the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#adding-validation). `this` obviously won't work, since you're not in the same object anymore.

Comment: It's not that you're not in the same object, it's more like you are not in the same "state" when using it in the form directly, you validate input data before object hydratation. Maybe what you're trying to achieve is more into validation groups?